# Removed the first element from the Array with a loop but the last element stored "undefined" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, undefined

So  i was learning Data Structures and i got confused with arrays  & in a question where got to delete the 1st(0th element) element from the array. I understood the logic but couldn't understand why the element at the last index got altered and it stored "undefined" now.
below is the code with output

```
//remove first element
let numbers = ["A","B","C","D"];
console.log(numbers);
for(let i=0 ;i<numbers.length;i++){
    numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
}
console.log(numbers)
```

this is the output

```
[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
[ 'B', 'C', 'D', undefined ]
```

why the last element is undefined now?

Comment: Because on the last iteration `i` is `3` in your example, and when you set it you are trying to use `numbers[4]` (because `i+1=4`) and `numbers[4]` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not actually remove the elements from the array, what you ended up doing was changing the position of the elements in the array. The last element is undefined because there is no value after D as such when you assign to numbers[3] the value becomes undefined.

```
numbers[4] = does not exist
numbers[3] = “D” 
numbers[2]= “C”
numbers[1]= “B”
numbers[0] = “A”

After change

numbers[3] = undefined
numbers[2]= “D”
numbers[1]= “C”
numbers[0] = “B”
```

Its better to use numbers.shift() to get rid of the first element

```
numbers[3] = “D” 
numbers[2]= “C”
numbers[1]= “B”
numbers[0] = “A”

After change

numbers[2]= “D”
numbers[1]= “C”
numbers[0] = “B”
```

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are zero based in javascript so eventually at the last interation of the loop you are setting last element of the array to 1 more than there is so that last element gets set to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Cuz you dont have „d” + 1 element in your array so if you try return element which isnt in your arr you always get undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the first item in array use the shift method. its undefined cause in the last iteration i+1 = 4, so numbers[4] doesnt exist.

```js
let numbers = ["A","B","C","D"];
console.log(numbers);

numbers.shift();
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What happend inside your code?

You were running a for loop through the array which assigns `nth` elemet to the `n+1th` element. This results in assiginig `1st` element to the `0th` element, `2nd` element to the `1st`, `3rd` to `2nd` so on. This resulted in assigning `3rd` element which is currently `'D'` to the `4th` element. The length of the array is 4, so the `4th` element of array i,e, `numbers[4]` will be `undefined`.

Exact solution to your problem. Use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let numbers = ["A","B","C","D"];
console.log(numbers);
numbers.splice(0, 1)
console.log(numbers)
```